# Python subprocess.call and subprocess.Popen giving me different outputs

Tags: python, subprocess

When using subprocess.call, the output is what is expected.

```
result = subprocess.call([securefx, '/NoPrompt', '/Q', '/RetryCount', retries, 
              '/RetryDelay', '1', '/Log', sfxLogFile, '/List', '/S', session])
```

Printing the result will output something like 
-533428 or 0

But when I run

```
args = [securefx, '/NoPrompt', '/Q', '/RetryCount', retries, '/RetryDelay', '1', 
       '/Log', sfxLogFile, '/List', '/S', session]
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = process.communicate()[0]
```

and print the result, I get blank or otherwise stderr = "None".

Why are they different? The reason I'm trying Popen even though call is working is because of this: [Python subprocess.call on sfxcl.exe not working from Windows 2003 Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922129/python-subprocess-call-on-sfxcl-exe-not-working-from-windows-2003-task-scheduler) <- thought I'd give it a go...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` returns a [Popen object](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects), which you can use to communicate with the process and get output, however `subprocess.call` will only return the return code of the process:

```
subprocess.call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.
```

So `subprocess.call` is basically equivalent to the following code, and only exists for convenience:

```
def call(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    p = subprocess.Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    return p.wait()
```

Comment: I found it! process.wait() will give me the same returncodes. :)